# Issues with google extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a very simple exstension, when you click it, it is supposed to open a new tab, and send the user away to www.simplewebstats.com like this:

```
http://simplewebstats.com/process.php?domain="Domain the user is browsing"
```

So if he is browsing google.com, he is supposed to get sent as

```
http://simplewebstats.com/process.php?domain=google.com
```

Here is what I have

Manifest.json

```
{
   "background_page": "background.html",
   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
   },
   "description": "A free SEO tool for webmasters to track and display web data from most websites. ",
   "name": "SimpleWebStats Site Report",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://www.simplewebstats.com/" ],
   "version": "1.2",
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.html

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

js.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.simplewebstats.com/process.php?ref=plugins&    processType=add&domain="+tab.url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1]});
    });
});
```

Nothing happens on click, where is the issue? I cannot seem to find it

Comment: Did you try looking at the background page Javascript console for errors? On a side note `chrome.tabs.getSelected` has been depreciated, use `chrome.tabs.query` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this with a bookmarklet.

```
javascript: (function() {
    var current_domain = window.location.href.replace(/^http\:\/\//,'');
    window.location.href = "http://www.simplewebstats.com/process.php?ref=plugins&processType=add&domain=" + current_domain;
})();
```